# How to pass query results from the results page to a different php page

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I know how to get search results from one page to another, but the scenario I'm in right now is that I have a search form (searchform.php) where the user enters search criteria into a field or fields, clicks the submit button and the results display in a table on the search.php page. Now what I need to do is send those query results to another page (list.php) which is a page formatted as a report. I've tried using $_SESSION, $_GET, foreach, etc. And I've also tried comparing my code with the code on the other pages on my site and on the internet, but to no avail. None seems to fit my situation. Right now I'm using $_SESSION and only getting the word "Array" in each column of the table and getting only one row of data. When I did get actual data from the query it only brought over the last result from the query. For example, the search.php showed 6 results, but the list.php page only showed the last result. I've spent days on this. Will someone please try to help me? 
Here is part of the code on my search.php page (it works - although I'm not sure I need the $_SESSION info in the middle):

```
if !empty($_POST['id'])||!empty($_POST['title'])||!empty($_POST['numavail'])||!empty($_POST['categoryname'])||!empty($_POST['genretype'])){
            $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['id']);
            $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['title']);
            $numavail = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['numavail']);
            $categoryname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['categoryname']);  
            $genretype = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['genretype']);  

            $query="SELECT * FROM dvd WHERE (title LIKE '%$title%')
            AND (numavail LIKE '%$numavail%')
            AND (categoryname LIKE '%$categoryname%')
            AND (genretype LIKE '%$genretype%')
            ORDER BY title ASC";

        }else {
            $query="SELECT * FROM dvd ORDER BY title ASC";
        }
        $result = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $query);
        $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($num > 0) { // If it ran OK, display all the records.
            echo "<h4>Your search returned $num records.</h4><p></p>";

        //Table header:
        echo '<table align="center" width="950px" cellspacing="0" border=".5px" ! important><tr>
        <th>Title</th><th>Qty</th><th>Category</th><th>Genre</th></tr>'; 
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        //Fetch all the records...

        session_start();
            $_SESSION['id']=['id'];
            $_SESSION['title']=['title'];
            $_SESSION['numavail']=['numavail'];
            $_SESSION['categoryname']=['categoryname'];
            $_SESSION['genretype']=['genretype'];

        echo '<td align="left" width="20%" height="25px">'.$row['title'].'</td>
            <td align="right" width="5%">'.$row['numavail'].'</td>
            <td align="left" width="20%">'.$row['categoryname'].'</a></td>
            <td align="left" width="30%">'.$row['genretype'].'</a></td>
            <td align="center" width="5%"><a href=../dvd/updateform.php?id='.$row['id'].'><em>Update</em></a></td>
            <td align="center" width="5%"><a href=../dvd/deleteconfirm.php?id='.$row['id'].'><em>Delete</em></a></td>
        </tr>
        ';
        }
        // End of While statement
        echo "</table>";
```

Here is part of the code on my list.php page (not working):

```
session_start();
    include ('../../includes/reportheader.php'); // Include the header file.
    echo ('<h1>DVD SEARCH RESULTS</h1>');


    //Table displaying records.
    '<div id="rpttable">';
    echo '<table align="center" width="750px" cellspacing="0" border=".5px" ! important><tr>
    <th>Movie Title</th><th>Qty</th><th>Category</th><th>Genre</th></tr>'; 
    echo '<td align="left" width="20%" height="25px">'.$_SESSION['title'].'</td>
        <td align="center" width="5%">'.$_SESSION['numavail'].'</td>
        <td align="left" width="20%">'.$_SESSION['categoryname'].'</td>
        <td align="left" width="30%">'.$_SESSION['genretype'].'</a></td>
    </tr>
    </div>
    ';
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: You cannot output (html, whitespaces, echos etc.) anything before `session_start();` or session will fail. Put it at the first line of your document. (unless you have output buffering on)

Comment: Got it. Thank you, Mr. Blue. I made this change in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `session_start();` at the first line of your document or else session will fail unless output buffering setting is on.

In your while loop, name your session variable properly so it won't mess with other session variables in the future. Also set the values of your session elements with that from $row variable.

**From:** `$_SESSION['id']=['id'];` - **to** - `$_SESSION['search_result']['id'][]=$row['id'];` - so on.

Also before your `while loop` you have to delete your previous search results before adding new ones by adding line `unset($_SESSION['search_result']);`. Else old and new results will be displayed together.

In **listing.php** you have to loop through `$_SESSION['search_result']` to display the passed search results. Something like:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($_SESSION['search_result']['id']); $i++ ){
            echo '<tr><td align="left" width="20%" height="25px">'.$_SESSION['search_result']['title'][$i].'</td>
                <td align="center" width="5%">'.$_SESSION['search_result']['numavail'][$i].'</td>
                <td align="left" width="20%">'.$_SESSION['search_result']['categoryname'][$i].'</td>
                <td align="left" width="30%">'.$_SESSION['search_result']['genretype'][$i].'</a></td>
            </tr>';
        }
```

Comment: Mr. Blue, thank you soooooo much. Your suggestions fixed all of my issues and made my files work like a charm. You are AWESOME!! Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use GET, POST method or Session, Cookie for passing data from one page to another page

Example

**GET and POST**

```
<form method="get" action="page2.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="varname" value="var_value">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

PHP code

```
//Using GET
$var_value = $_GET['varname'];

//Using POST
$var_value = $_POST['varname'];

//Using GET, POST or COOKIE.
$var_value = $_REQUEST['varname'];
```

Change the method for the form to post if you want to do it via post.
Both are equally insecure, although GET is easier to hack.
GET method can handle less amount of data.
For handling higher amount of data, use POST Methode and also check the "post_max_size" in php.ini file.

**Session**

```
//One page 1
$_COOKIE['varname'] = $var_value;

//On page 2
$var_value = $_COOKIE['varname'];
```

**Cookie**

```
//One page 1
$_COOKIE['varname'] = $var_value;

//On page 2
$var_value = $_COOKIE['varname'];
```

The big difference between sessions and cookies is that the sessions value stored on the server and cookies stored in client browser memory.